# How do you reliably generate consecutive numbers?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on a project (a web application written in PHP using Symfony 2) in which there is a requirement that various security related events are logged. It's also required that the events in the log file are numbered consecutively (I guess so that is not so easy delete items).

I'll be using [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) (included with Symfony) for the logging and I know I can add the numbers to the records with a Processor.

What I however I don't know is how to actually reliably generate the consecutive numbers. With "reliably" I mean: no gaps and no duplicate numbers.

The only solution I can think of is let the database (MySQL via Doctrine) generate the numbers by using a dummy table with an auto-increment ID, which however seems to be a bit of an overhead for logging.

What are other strategies for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate an auto-increment id with a single file, which contains the last id. A lock prevents race conditions:

```
$fp = fopen('/path/to/id.file', 'r+');
flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
$lastId = fgets($fp);
$currentId = $lastId + 1;
fseek($fp, 0);
fputs($currentId);

// place logging here...

flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot about file locking. I'll have a look into this. Thanks.

Comment: `fputs($fp, $currentId);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write to a file, I guess the only thing reliable is to read the maximum number from this file before writing a new record – and use file locking while doing it to avoid a [TOCTTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) problem. So basically the stuff that a database *transaction* does for you, but with files :-)

Maybe you don’t need to lock and read the whole log file every time – it could also be enough to record only the last number into a separate “counter” file, and have that locked during reading the last number, writing to the log file and updating the number in your counter file.